# Assets 2.3.2 Lib file - Causes PHP error

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, php, php-errors

After updating to the latest versions of the Assets extension for Expression Engine. When I am logged in as a Super Admin I get the following PHP error, I don't get this error when logged in as a different user.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: libraries/Assets_lib.php

Line Number: 814

This is caused by this following line of code in the Library file (line 814):

> if (!(count($full_folder_list) == 1 && $full_folder_list[0] ==
>   ":any:"))

Is there a fix for this line, I am not sure what:

> $full_folder_list[0] == ":any:"

means but this is the part that causing the error.

**I am looking for a fix for this?**

I am using Expression Engine 2.7.2

Assets Version 2.3.2

PHP Version 5.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ugh, wasn't logged in properly....

They sent me this on email support:

*If you could just replace line 814 in Assets_lib.php file with*

```
if (!(count($full_folder_list) == 1 && reset($full_folder_list) == ":any:"))
```

*you should be fine :)*

Answer (score 0):

They sent me this on email support:

"If you could just replace line 814 in Assets_lib.php file with "if (!(count($full_folder_list) == 1 && reset($full_folder_list) == ":any:"))" you should be fine :)"